# Get IP address using Action Script?

Tags: php, actionscript-3, actionscript, ip-address

Is it possible to get client IP address through Flash (swf) Action Script 3 and then pass it to php file to store it in database?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No need to do it in flash, just do it on your server in php "$ip=@$REMOTE_ADDR;"

Comment: $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] would be the preferred way of doing it.

Answer (score 2):

No, the client IP address is not available in ActionScript 3.  The recommended approach is to have it reflected by server-side code.

See http://www.actionscript.org/forums/showthread.php3?s=&threadid=20123

Answer (score 1):

```
function GetUserIP() {
    var js="function get_userIP(){return java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress();}";
    var userIPInfo:String=ExternalInterface.call(js).toString();
    return userIPInfo;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I know YES!! But I am wondering about the reason of doing that. You can just use PHP for get the IP Address..

EDIT : Had a research.. Changing my answer. I think there is less possibility to do it with Flash..

Comment: I have a screen which whole thing must in flash, hence i must use flash to get the ip and then pass it to php. Since you say YES, can show me how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Like the above answer, use PHP (or other scripting language) to pass the IP address as a param value into your flash movie and you'll have it available at runtime.

Another option is to use the ExternalInterface to make a call to a server-side PHP script or something of the like to return the IP address.

Answer (score 0):

As Alex says, pass it in via flashvars, but that PHP should really be:

```
$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
```

The json extension is handy for wrIting out flash vars, e.g. for passing to swfobject:

```
var flashvars = { IP : <?=json_encode($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])?> };
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to grab the real IP address via Flash Actionscript.

You'll believe it after you visited this site (click on Flash tab):

http://AnalyzeMy.net

Comment: You are using PHP script to obtain IP address, it is no different comparing to previous answers.

Answer (score 0):

Despite what most are saying - there is a difference somehow. I used to run a rather large forum (200k+) and most banned members were eventually caught again once they entered our chat (Flash). While the VB software (using php) would give one IP (Usually through a Proxy/Network) , the Chat (Flash) would in fact give us their True IP. 
Don't ask me to explain it - I barely get by with PHP myself ...

Comment: If you cannot explain it, don't write it. Flash files run on the client side and cannot read out the clients network-ip.

Comment: Actually he is right. I struggled all day to pass a Flash IP verification. I managed to pass a few layers of security by using a Proxy (wich wasn't enough) and then a VPN. The VPN offered me full access to the website but not to the Flash player. I did some research and Flash can access your real IP regardless of your efforts unless your force a virtual machine to have the VPN, not having any links at all with your main system. Check it on the internet: passing flash ip verification, it's not a subject widely discussed but it's very intresting.