# How to get host ip in Flex?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

When it in PHP, we already know using

> $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']

we can a host IP, what if it in AS3?

thanks

Comment: duplicate question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/695854/get-ip-address-using-action-script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't get the client's IP address in a Flash SWF.  This is not exposed via the Flash Player, I assume for security sandbox reasons.

However, on the server side you can access it on any remote call using the same method you describe in your post.  ( I assume that is the PHP way to access the CGI variable).

Comment: if i want to redirect to page in different directory in my computer what must i do? it's okay if my IP is static but it's not like that

Comment: Do you mean you want to redirect from one directory on a web server to another directory on a web server?  Then use navigateToURL to do so.  However that follow up question has no relation to your original question.

Comment: I also want to ad; that in most cases the HTTP_Host will not give you an IP Address.  It will give you the host name.  REMOTE_ADDR will most likely give you the IP Address.

Comment: Sorry, I should learn anymore about navigateToURL before I post this question. thanks bro.